# Overriding Block issues?

Tags: magento2, overrides, module, magento2-dev-beta

I want override Block **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery**
this is code in file di.xml

**Edited**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View\Gallery" />
    </config>
```

**Code file Gallery.php**

```
    namespace Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
    {
        protected function _toHtml()
        {
            $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery'));
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

       /**
       * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
       */
       protected $_scopeConfig;

       /**
         * Template image only
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_templateImage = 'Xyaddons_Productzoom::product/image.phtml';

      protected function _prepareLayout()
        {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View\Gallery', 'xyaddons.productzoom')->setTemplate('Xyaddons_Productzoom::produtc/image.phtml');}
}
```

when run code don't running  image.phtml and not override Block **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery**. What wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you removed cache?

Why your extended class `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery` but try override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery`? (I think you have error in class `for` in preferences)

Why you don't rewrite block `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>` and try override class?

Comment: Thanks @antonohorodnyk. i removed cache and edit extended class in my question. Why you don't rewrite block....? Because I want create a module. when  setup new site i don't need find block and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

use plugin to override the block or model 
ex
in di.xml (i took ex of block, model and controller of product )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="inroduct-custom-module" type="Sugarcode\Test\Model\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="getname-test-module" type="Sugarcode\Test\Model\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="product-cont-test-module" type="Sugarcode\Test\Model\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

in plugin that 
app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\Plugin\Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Plugin;

class Product
{        
    public function beforeSetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $name)
    {
        return array('(' . $name . ')');
    }

     public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return '|' . $result . '|';
    } 

     public function afterGetLabel($subject, $result)
    {
        $result=$result.' Custom';
        return $result;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        echo 'I Am in Local Controller Before <br>';
        $returnValue = $proceed(); // it get you old function return value
        //$name='#'.$returnValue->getName().'#';
        //$returnValue->setName($name);
        echo 'I Am in Local Controller  After <br>';
        return $returnValue;// if its object make sure it return same object which you addition data
    }


}
```

this the best way of override file 
if you use preference then you will miss magento core function at the time of upgrade
i hope it will help you